# Set mpifort as compiler in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors, mpi

I'm a newby!

I'm developing an MPI C project in Eclipse and, since I've to use p3dfft, I must set **mpifort** as compiler in Eclipse.

Unfortunately until now I hadn't get positive results.

Eclipse console simply prints:

```
make all 
Building target: p3dfft
Invoking: MacOS X C Linker
/usr/local/bin/mpifort -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o "p3dfft"  ./src/p3dfft.o   -lmpi -lmpi
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
gfortran in your PATH.

Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in
one of several possible environment variables.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
make: *** [p3dfft] Error 1
```

I'm stuck here... What can I do? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is `gfortran` in your `$PATH` ?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, how can I check what is my $PATH?

Comment: `which gfortran`

Comment: gfortran is in the same path of mpifort: /usr/local/bin/

Comment: Ok, I've setted up the $(PATH), but now a new problem arise:


`make all 
make: echo: No such file or directory
make: *** [src/p3dfft.o] Error 1`


How can I handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved thanks to the help of Gilles!

I've started a new project, in `Project -> Properties -> Fortran Build -> Environment` I've updated the `PATH` with the entry `/usr/local/bin` where mpifort & gfortran are located and everything goes fine.